# react component is unable to locate my CSS class

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

```
import { classes } from './DropdownMenu.module.css';

function DropdownMenu() {
    return(
        <div className={classes["dropdown"]}>
```

I've defined a file called DropdownMenu.module.css in the same directory as the DropdownMenu.js file

The CSS in the file looks like

```
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
}
```

I am not sure why it can't find it. I've tried using **classes.dropdown** and that didn't help. I've also cleared my browser cache and reinstalled my packages with npm install.

The error I receive is

> Cannot read property 'dropdown' of undefined

Comment: Are you still have problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the default export. Try importing it like this:

`import classes from './DropdownMenu.module.css';`

and then use it like this:

`<div className={classes.dropdown}>`

Comment: Thanks. It's 2 AM here and I can't believe i made that mistake!

Comment: I've learned the hard way that coding at 2 AM is not a good idea, except when you get up at 1PM :)